# How long does it take for my own website to fully update and show the new changes that I have made?

Tags: html, css, web, server

I have recently made some changes to my website, like changing the font, customised the scroll bar and positioned some elements. After uploading it to my web hosting server, I have noticed that nothing has changed.

I know that by clearing the cache in my browser I can see the changes and everything's perfect, but is there any other way? If I wait longer , will the changes automatically be made? if so, how long will it take?

Comment: What makes you think this is based on time? Simply clear the cache.

Comment: Which type of web server are you using? It may be the case that you need to re-start the web-server for it to take effect. There could also be some caching happening on the server side which you may need to refresh.

If you could give us some more insight into the tech stack that you are using that would really help.

Comment: As @Ashley has suggested we'd need to know about the stuff you are using. Also, in your own browser what are the settings for cache? Does it expire after time etc. There are several ways of forcing a reload but it depends on what your set up is.

Comment: Hi @SebastionSimon,@Ashley, @A Haworth, I think I created a misunderstanding , Im new to web designing , learned html, css and created a website and used a web hosting provider - Hostinger to upload my website. So I dont know if web server was the right word for it. My issue is not seeing the changes for myself. For example when I make a new change to the website, if a person who has already seen my website previously open up my website, they wont be able to see the new changes. Not everyone will want to clear cache to see the new changes and they might not even know if a change has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically the point of *caching*: information will be outdated for some who have cached content, *but* that cached content will load a lot faster for them and they don't need to re-download everything from your server all the time. You can control how long and how exactly clients should cache your content by [setting appropriate HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching). How to do that exactly will differ based on your server/host. But in the end it's always a tradeoff between loading speed (more cached content, fewer requests on subsequent visits), server load (more caching, fewer requests, less server load, more capacity for more users), and information not being entirely up to date.

Comment: Ok so if I were to set appropriate HTTP headers, others wont need to clear their cache to view my website changes?

Comment: Yes. The most sensible thing is probably to set ETag and/or Modified headers, and allow caching for some length of time like 1 hour or so; whatever you're comfortable with for information to be out of date. So clients may not see your new site for an hour or so, and can also use conditional If-Modified-Since and/or If-Not-Match requests when they check for updates again. — You yourself will probably always want to clear your cache/force refresh so you don't have to wait. Though you could also configure the server to suppress caching headers just for you, via various means.

Answer (score 1):

I know that repeatedly reloading a web page can cause some issues with loading new content. When this happens, I usually close the tab as well as the browser.

If that still doesn’t work, trying switching to a different browser (Eg. from chrome to edge).

After this you could try to clear your cache (which is undesirable as it takes time and is inconvenient).

If problems are still occurring, either the issue is with your web server’s speed or your browser’s cache.
If you really get desperate, you could try restarting your web server (if you own it).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the incognito mode to see the changes.
You can also try Ctrl/CMD+Shift+R to perform a hard reload of a web page (in Chrome).